# Почему надо писать string.join(list), а не list.join(string)?

Tags: python, строки, join

Меня это всегда смущало. Мне кажется что это:

```
my_list = ["Hello", "world"]
print(my_list.join("-"))
# результат: "Hello-world"
```

было бы понятнее, чем это:

```
my_list = ["Hello", "world"]
print("-".join(my_list))
# результат: "Hello-world"
```

Есть ли конкретная причина, по которой надо писать именно так?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Why is it string.join(list) instead of list.join(string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring) от участника [Evan Fosmark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49701/evan-fosmark)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493819/why-is-it-string-joinlist-instead-of-list-joinstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потому, что любой итерируемый объект может быть объединен (например: список, кортеж, словарь, множество), но его содержимое и «объединитель» должны быть строками.

Например:

```
'_'.join(['welcome', 'to', 'stack', 'overflow'])
'_'.join(('welcome', 'to', 'stack', 'overflow'))
```

```
'welcome_to_stack_overflow'
```

Использование чего-то другого, кроме строк, вызовет следующую ошибку:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493842/14227417) от участника [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44743/recursive)</sub>